# load resources from build directory or not

Tags: java, json, gradle, build, resources

I need to load some files in my app and read/write on some json files.
I created these files in the resources folder and I get them using ClassLoader and getResource().
The problem is that when I use the ClassLoader I get the file from the build directory, so when I write on the file the changes doesn't affect the file in the src folder but only the file in the build folder, and when I rerun the app the changes are discarded.

I use Gradle and IntelliJ

Comment: resources are meant to be read-only - and should come from the build directory (after deployment from the deployment/distribution folder/JAR). Writable files are better saved in the user directory (or an own sub-directory there), or in the working directory (is eventually the same as the deployment one)

Comment: @user16320675 thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should put all json files under "res/raw" and then read them.

If you are writing anything during runtime the files should be copied to Internal / External storage and then read or write from this new copy.

Comment: Thanks, and the what would be the right location to save the copy in?

Comment: You can use the Enviroment.getExternalStorage() method more info here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: I'm not developing for android but it's a desktop application, is it the same?

Comment: My apologies no they are not same for desktop you should use the Java File classes.  Regarding where you should save your copy you can save them where your classes are placed.